# How to set Separator`s color to invisible in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

This how it looks now:

```
    <Separator Height="10" Margin="0" Width="168" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Background="SteelBlue"/>
```

The problem, that  I don't know what color `Background`  will be needed? Is there any way out? Or  need to know what color I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Invisible" Brush in WPF is called `Transparent`, you can set `Background="Transparent"` to set the Separator to invisble.

Or you can set the `Visibiliy="Hidden"` to preserve the space of the control without showing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transparent

```
<Separator Height="10" Margin="0" Width="168" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Background="Transparent"/>
```